# Online version of Ridge Regression Classifier in ski-kitlearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying a range of Online classifiers in the ski-kitlearn library to train a model from huge data. I found there are many classifiers supporting the partial_fit  allowing for incremental learning. I want to use the Ridge Regression classifier in this setting, but could not find it in the implementation. Is there an alternative model that can do this in sklearn?

Comment: Pplease do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

`sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier`, its loss function contain ‘hinge’, ‘log’, ‘modified_huber’, ‘squared_hinge’, ‘perceptron’

`sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor`, its default loss function is `squared_loss`,  The possible values are ‘squared_loss’, ‘huber’, ‘epsilon_insensitive’, or ‘squared_epsilon_insensitive’

Comment: this answer does not seem to adress the question.